# controller method return value without jwt token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have configured `Jwt/tymon` API authentication and use custom model, what I want is controller function should not be accessed without the token generated by JWT on login,

**Route**

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api'
    // 'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('auth/mpalogin', 'MpaLoginController@mpaLogin')->name('login');
    Route::post('auth/mpalogout', 'MpaLoginController@logout');
    Route::post('auth/mparefresh', 'MpaLoginController@refresh');
    Route::post('auth/mpame', 'MpaLoginController@myinfo');
    Route::post('auth/mpag', 'MpaLoginController@awain');
});
```

**CONTROLLER -> The `awain` method at the last is accessed without sending the token, which I don't want, I want every method that I create in this controller should be accessed only by token**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Config;
use JWTAuth;
use JWTAuthException;
use App\Mpa;

class MpaLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        Config::set('jwt.user', Mpa::class);
        Config::set('auth.providers', ['users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => Mpa::class,
            ]]);
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['mpaLogin']]);
    }

    public function mpaLogin(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ]);
            }
        } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'success',
            'result' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'message' => 'I am front mpa',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function myinfo()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Mpa Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    public function awain()
    {
        return response()->json("xyz");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

1. Add this middleware file in your `App\Http\Middleware` folder.
   Filename must be `JWTMiddleware.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Authentication\Auth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class JWTMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (is_null($request->bearerToken())) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Token required.'], 401);
        }

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
            $apy = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();

        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['error' => 'Session Expired.', 'status_code' => 401], 401);

        } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['error' => 'Token invalid.', 'status_code' => 401], 401);

        } catch (JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent' => $e->getMessage()], 401);

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. register this middleware in `$routeMiddleware` of `App\Http\kernel.php` file.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
       ....
       ....
       'jwt' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWTMiddleware::class,
   ];
```

3. Add this middleware to your Route group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => [ 'jwt', 'jwt.auth']], function () {
    ....
    ....
    });
```

Working example Repo:
 https://github.com/kennethtomagan/laravel-5-api-boilerplate/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['mpaLogin']]);
```

With this

```
$this->middleware('api', ['except' => ['mpaLogin']]);
```

Also remove the middleware from the route group. As you are adding the middleware code in the construct of the controller.

Comment: thank you for you answer, but `awain` method is being accessed without token(which is not correct)...token must be needed if you want any method of the controller is running.